# Which unit of measurement is contained by a sentinel 2 pixel?

Tags: sentinel-2

After downloading MSIL2C sentinel data for quite sometime for observational purposes, I now need to look into change analysis using the NIR Band. Looking at the pixel values, I notice woodland vegetation is up to 2000-3000 units and residential areas around 1000-1500.
What is the unit of measurement assigned to the pixel? Is this radiometric intensity?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the processing level of the image that you download.

Raw satellite images exist in DN number, which are usually directly proportionnal to the irradiance. But usually the Sentienl-2 data that you can download are either L1C or L2B.

L1C are top of atmosphere reflectance, that is the ratio between the incoming light and the light reflected after travelling through the atmosphere. Because it is a ratio, it has no unit and is in theory between 0 and 1, but stored as an integer to reduce the size of the data.

L2B are top of canopy reflectance. This means that the TOA reflectance has been processed in order to remove the effect of the atmosphere on the signal. If the data comes from ESA's hub, the algorithm used is SEN2COR.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on what product that you downloaded.
If the file contains the designation `MSIL1C`, then the measurement is what is commonly referred to as `Digital Numbers`, which are correlated to `radiometric intensity`.
If you instead downloaded preprocessed data (`L2A`-data), then it is likely that what you see represents `surface reflectance`, which is the standard way of presenting such data. It is usually a scaled-to-integers percentage-value that shows how much of the incoming light is reflected from the surface.